# How would I slice this matrix in matlab parfor loop?

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I have a following matlab code which I can't figure out how to slice the matrix called "data".

Briefly, what the code does is:

At each iteration, create a re-ordering called "newOrder" and
call a function "train" with a re-ordered vector "y" and re-ordered matrix "data".
Here, "re-ordering" uses all elements not a subset of them. It's critical that the loop runs fast so I'm concerned about this warning.

```
w = []; data = sparse(double(X(:,selTrain)));

parfor ci = 1:length(classes)
    y = 2*(imageClass(selTrain)==ci)'-1;   
    newOrder = [find(y==1); find(y==-1)];
    this_svm = train(y(newOrder), data(:, newOrder), ' -s 3 -B 1 -c 10 -q', 'col');    
    w(:,ci) = this_svm.w';
end
```

I do not get an error but a warning: The variable data is indexed but not sliced, in a parfor loop. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

I need to do this for a combinatorially many re-orderings.
So I've spent numerous time hopelessly trying bunch of things..
Any help or suggestions would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to compute in parallel all the orders of the `data` matrix to run several SVM `train` simultaneously? It's not entire clear to me. Can you give me more details?

Comment: Not all the orders of data. For each classes, I want to reorder the data matrix and call the train function.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?  Could you add that to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've already worked-around the problem; however, for completeness the problem is that `neworder`, which you use to index data, is not related to the parfor loop index `ci` in a way that allows data to be sliced. The proximate cause for this failure is that `neworder` is a vector and not a scalar. Right away that prevents matlab from slicing data. Even if that were not the case, matlab can't slice data when it can't relate the loop index (`ci`) to the variable index (`neworder`).